# Try/Catch statement not working

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am having some trouble with this particular try/catch block. It should work, but every time I enter a letter, I still get a `NumberFormatException`. Can anyone identify the problem with this code?

```
         try {
          if (convertToNum > 4) {
            System.out.println("You entered a number that is too high");
          }
          else if (convertToNum < 1) {
            System.out.println("You entered a number that is too low");
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("You subtracted " + convertToNum +
                               " from the pile.");
          }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e){
          System.out.println ("You entered an invalid number");
        }
        return convertToNum;
      }
```

Comment: There is no number parsing code in this sample. Please provide the rest!

Comment: Huh?  There is nothing inside your `try` block that could throw an exception.

Comment: I can bet the exception is thrown _before_ the `try` block, in the code which parses a string into `convertToNum`.

Comment: Is the value of `convertToNum` in the right format?

Comment: Not sure why this was closed... it's pretty clear what is being asked here: "Why is the `NumberFormatException` not being caught?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever is throwing the `NumberFormatException` is not in the `try` block... there are no method calls (beyond `System.out.println`) in there, whatsoever.

Put the number conversion method call inside the `try` block and you'll be fine.

Comment: No, it answers the question.  It's an answer -- the correct one.

Comment: i put the 'Integer.parseInt' into the string but now the return statement is messing up...

Comment: If you declare `convertToInt` inside the `try` block, then it will be out of scopy when you attempt to return it. Either put the `return` into the `try` block or declare `convertToInt` outside the try block, but don't do the `parseInt` until you're *inside* the `try` block.